# TestNG can't create ResultView on Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, testng

I've installed the current version of TestNG from the "Eclipse Marketplace" 6.9.5.201508210528 on Eclipse Kepler (Build id: 20130614-0229) and the installation seems to succeed but TestNG's log window shows the error message:

```
Could not create the view: org.testng.eclipse.ResultView
```

Besides the TestNG view is not listed under:

Window > Show View > Other... > Java

and it is neither listed under:

Windows > 
Preferences

I have tried downgrading TestNG to a 6.8 version but it brakes Eclipse.

Does someone has any suggestion?

**Resolved**

Using a colleagues TestNG folder was the only solution. Both the related contents of the "features" and "plugins" folders were necessary.

Comment: You should upgrade Eclipse

Comment: The problem is that Kepler is the version we use for development, so we want to use the same version all of us. Other colleagues don't have the same problem but they use an earlier version of TestNG that I can't find.

Comment: New testng plugin doesn't support old Eclipse. But you should be able to install old plugin from your colleagues directory

Comment: Oh, I hadn't have that idea, thanks! I'll try it.

Comment: Thanks juherr. Until we move to Luna this fix will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

juherr suggestion was the only solution I found. Using a colleagues TestNG folder I copied the related contents of both the "features" and "plugins" folders and pasted the to my Eclipse.

TestNG works perfectly know.

If someone else is in the same situation upgrading Eclipse would be the solution, unless you can get a version that works in Kepler from someone. I couldn't find one in TestNG's [repository for old versions.](http://beust.com/eclipse-old)